# Excel VBA Macro from MS Access - object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Answer: Set XlBook = Xl.Workbooks.Open(MySheetPath)

I am trying to troubleshoot someone else's macro.  They have some macros in an Access DB that effect an excel workbook.

There are two segments of code in question.

```
XlBook.Sheets("Item Detail Frozen").Select
Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets("Item Detail Frozen")
With XlSheet
   XlSheet.Cells.Select
   XlSheet.Range("A1").Activate
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End With

XlBook.Sheets("Item Detail").Select
Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets("Item Detail")
With XlSheet
    Xl.WindowState = xlMinimized
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    .Range("A1:D1").Select
    .Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
End With
```

I get "Object variable or with block variable not set" on 
"Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp"

And if I comment that out I then get it on "ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll"

I got around that one by actively setting the active book, then I get it on 
".Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select"  Same error block/variable not set.  I'm just at a loss here.  When i did macro recorder in excel the same type of macro works but when coming from Access it doesn't like it.

Here is the code in its entirety.

```
    Option Compare Database
    Option Explicit

    Function FileExists(ByVal FileToTest As String) As Boolean
       FileExists = (Dir(FileToTest) <> "")
    End Function
    Sub DeleteFile(ByVal FileToDelete As String)

    DeleteFile:

       If FileExists(FileToDelete) Then 'See above
          On Error GoTo DeleteFile_ErrorHandler
          Kill FileToDelete
       End If
       Exit Sub
    DeleteFile_ErrorHandler:
       On Error Resume Next
       MsgBox "There was an error deleteing the file(s), " & FileToDelete & _
              ".  Check to see if you or any one has any of these files open and have them closed; then press OK.  "

    End Sub



    Public Function PrepareOutputFile() As Variant
        'Variables to refer to Excel and Objects
        Dim MySheetPath As String
        Dim Xl As Excel.Application
        Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim XlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim NewFilePath As String
        Dim NewPathDir As String
        Dim LastSlashPos      As String
        Dim AttachmentDir      As String
        Dim NewFileWildCard      As String
        Dim NewFileName As String


        ' Tell it location of actual Excel file
        MySheetPath = "W:\Sams-LibertySport\Sams-LibertySport- Week #x - as of mm-dd-yyyy.xls"

        'Open Excel and the workbook
        Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set XlBook = GetObject(MySheetPath)

        'Make sure excel is visible on the screen
        Xl.Visible = True
        XlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True

        XlBook.Sheets("Item Detail Frozen").Select
        Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets("Item Detail Frozen")
        'With XlSheet

         '   .Cells.Select
          '  .Range("A1:D1").Activate
           ' Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

        'End With
        With XlSheet
           XlSheet.Cells.Select
           XlSheet.Range("A1").Activate
           Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

        End With

        XlBook.Sheets("Item Detail").Select
        Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets("Item Detail")
        With XlSheet
            Xl.WindowState = xlMinimized
            ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
            .Range("A1:D1").Select
            .Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
            Selection.Copy
        End With

        XlBook.Sheets("Item Detail Frozen").Select
        Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets("Item Detail Frozen")
        With XlSheet

            .Range("A1").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            .Range("A1").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            .Cells.Select
            .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            Xl.CutCopyMode = False
            ChDir "W:\"
            NewFilePath = Replace(Replace(Replace(MySheetPath, "W:\", "R:\"), _
                           "#x", "#" & CInt(Right(DLookup("EndingWmWeek", "Period", "PeriodCode='LW'"), 2))), _
                          "mm-dd-yyyy", Format(DLookup("[As-of Date]", "As-of Date"), "mm-dd-yyyy"))
            LastSlashPos = InStrRev(NewFilePath, "\")
            AttachmentDir = Left(NewFilePath, LastSlashPos - 1) & "\EmailAttachments"
            NewFileWildCard = Mid(NewFilePath, LastSlashPos + 1, InStr(LastSlashPos, NewFilePath, "-", vbTextCompare) - LastSlashPos) & "*.*"
            NewFileName = Mid(NewFilePath, LastSlashPos + 1, Len(NewFilePath) - LastSlashPos)


            While FileExists(NewFilePath)
                DeleteFile NewFilePath
            Wend
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
                NewFilePath, FileFormat:= _
                xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
                , CreateBackup:=False

        End With
        XlBook.Sheets("TopLine Overview").Select
        Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets("TopLine Overview")
        XlSheet.Range("A1").Select
        XlSheet.Range("A1").Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.Save

        'Clean up and end with worksheet visible on the screen
        ActiveWorkbook.Close (False) 'Discard changes
        Set XlSheet = Nothing
        Set XlBook = Nothing
        Xl.Quit
        Set Xl = Nothing

        While FileExists(AttachmentDir & "\" & NewFileWildCard)
            DeleteFile AttachmentDir & "\" & NewFileWildCard
        Wend
        FileCopy NewFilePath, AttachmentDir & "\" & NewFileName

    End Function


    Public Sub PrepareDownloadedMdbFiles()

        'Variables to refer to Excel and Objects
        Dim MyDBPath As String
        Dim Db As Database
        Dim NewDBName As String

        Dim fdr As String
        Dim filenames() As String
        Dim FileIndex As Integer
        Dim fileCount As Integer
        FileIndex = 0

        filenames = GetFileNames("W:\lib394a_*.mdb")
        For FileIndex = 0 To UBound(filenames) - 1

            fdr = filenames(FileIndex)
            'Open Database
            Set Db = Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("W:\" & fdr)
            Dim td As TableDef
            NewDBName = ""
            For Each td In Db.TableDefs
                If Left(td.Name, 4) <> "Msys" Then
                    NewDBName = td.Name
                End If
            Next td
            Db.Close

            If NewDBName <> "" Then

                DeleteFile "W:\" & NewDBName & ".mdb"
                Name "W:\" & fdr As "W:\" & NewDBName & ".mdb"

            End If
        Next FileIndex


    End Sub

    Public Function GetFileNames(Template As String) As String()

        'Given a FileName template such as W:\ab*.*, return an array of filenames

        Dim MyDBPath As String
        Dim Db As Database
        Dim NewDBName As String

        Dim fdr As String
        Dim filenames() As String
        Dim FileIndex As Integer
        Dim fileCount As Integer
        FileIndex = 0
        ReDim filenames(0)

        fdr = Dir(Template)
        Do While fdr <> ""
            ReDim Preserve filenames(FileIndex + 1)
            filenames(FileIndex) = fdr
            FileIndex = FileIndex + 1
            fdr = Dir()
        Loop

        GetFileNames = filenames

    End Function
```

I now Altered it to

```
XlBook.Sheets("Item Detail Frozen").Select
Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets("Item Detail Frozen")

XlSheet.Cells.Clear

XlBook.Sheets("Item Detail").Select
Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets("Item Detail")
With XlSheet
    Xl.WindowState = xlMinimized
    XlBook.RefreshAll
    XlSheet.Range("A1:D1").Select
    XlSheet.Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
End With
```

Now the error is on XlSheet.Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select  and it is the same not set error.

Answer (score 0):

Oh-
I think you're getting the error on the Set.

```
Set XlBook = Xl.Workbooks.Open(MySheetPath)
```

This deletes all data on the worksheet, so why not just:

```
Worksheets(("Item Detail Frozen").Cells.Clear
```

There are many times, where the error does not indicate what is wrong, particularly when controlling one office product from another.  When you remove the line, and the error is occurring on the following line, it is a clear indication that it is not causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving all original code in but fixing 
    Set XlBook = Xl.Workbooks.Open(MySheetPath)

Fixed all errors.  It seems using the other method of opening the excel file wasn't the most ideal.  Thank you for your help.